# What is the practical purpose of an epsilon NFA?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

If for every $\epsilon$-NFA their exists an equivalent NFA what is the purpose of ever using an $\epsilon$-NFA? I am having trouble understanding what the practical purpose of using one would be.

Comment: http://compgroups.net/comp.compilers/nfa-dfa-why-use-epsilon-transitions/9619

Comment: What is the practical purpose of Java and Haskell? After all, Turing machines and lambda calculus are just as powerful, so why do we need these very complicated languages?

Comment: Well said Sir..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purely convenience.  It's like, in a programming language, why have `for` loops, if every `for` loop could alternatively be written as a `while` loop?  Convenience.  It's sometimes convenient to be able to use epsilon-transitions, when defining NFAs.  For instance, when converting a regexp to a NFA, the construction is arguably a bit simpler (easier to understand) if you allow yourself to use epsilon-transitions.

Answer (score 2):

Given a regular expression constructing an equivalent NFA with epsilon is easier  than constructing equivalent DFA. Also given two DFAs you can easily construct NFAs with epsilon moves accept concatenation, intersection, union, and Kleene closure of the languages. Look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) for example.

Comment: NFAs without epsilon are only slightly less convenient for these constructions than those with, and cause fewer inconveniences elsewhere.

Comment: @Raphael, try to construct an NFA without epsilon move for the following reg exp and feel the real convenience of using NFA with epsilon moves: $(a^*ab + b^*ab(ab +c)^*)^*$

Comment: Done it before; just change the standard construction to do the epsilon-closure directly. Not nice, but not *too* bad either. I encountered that variant in the context of proving that some logic was as powerful as NFA; *that* construction would have been *very* awkward had the FA been allowed to have epsilon-transitions. (Not that there had not been other ways around this, but I never claimed that there weren't.) Anyway, the point is: comparing epsilon-NFA with DFA is only half the story; you need to include non-epsilon-NFA in the comparison.